# How to deal with the RpcError: 1010?

Tags: staking, error

When i submit a WND  staking chill and staking unbond transaction,the console appears the err, How to deal with the RpcError: 1010?

```
2022-10-14 23:16:49 error: RPC-CORE: submitExtrinsic(extrinsic: Extrinsic): Hash:: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction is outdated
2022-10-14 23:16:49 error: txsubmit RpcError: 1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction is outdated
```

Comment: Did you submit the transaction multiple times? And were you able to get one of the transactions to succeed?

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with [Transaction Validity](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/transaction-lifecycle/#validating-and-queuing-transactions).

Here is the error in Substrate:

```rust
InvalidTransaction::Stale => "Transaction is outdated",
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/25388397aab20a24e2be55103dda95011aa04d7c/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L98

If you look up the enum variant `InvalidTransaction::Stale` you will find the following:

```rust
/// General error to do with the transaction being outdated (e.g. nonce too low).
    Stale,
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/07e1b6d72747f3cde49e85e4ff68ff158daebe16/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L47-L48

It could be that your nonce is too low (old).

> In case the runtime returns an Invalid error it means the transaction
> cannot be added to a block at all. Extracting the actual reason of
> invalidity gives more details about the source. For instance Stale
> transaction just indicates the transaction was already included in a
> block

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/transaction-pool/README.md#invalid-transaction

As noted in the [Polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-errors#common-errors), try increasing the nonce to +1 of the current nonce. You can check the current nonce by inspecting the address you're using to send the transaction.